# 06533. 00000 - "Subscript beyond count"

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have this plsql block that populates a table with information of two other tables and I have to use a variable array:

```
DECLARE nombre_grupo VARCHAR2(15);
    direccion_tipo direccion;
    persona_tipo persona;
    personas_array personas := personas();
    CURSOR departamento IS
    SELECT * FROM departamentos;
    CURSOR empleado IS
    SELECT * FROM empleados, departamentos
    WHERE empleados.dept_no = departamentos.dept_no;
    i INTEGER;
BEGIN
    FOR departamento IN (SELECT * FROM departamentos) LOOP
    nombre_grupo := departamento.dnombre;
    i := 1;
    personas_array := personas();
    FOR empleado IN (SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE dept_no = departamento.dept_no) LOOP
        direccion_tipo := DIRECCION(departamento.loc, 'NULL', empleado.dir);
        personas_array(i) := PERSONA(empleado.emp_no, empleado.apellido,
        direccion_tipo, empleado.fecha_alt);
        i := i + 1;
    END LOOP;
    INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (nombre_grupo, personas_array);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Here's the type personas:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE personas AS VARRAY(5) OF PERSONA
```

So when I execute that block and it reaches the `personas_array(i)` bit, it exits the execution with "subscript beyond count" error, no matter what value of i. What am I missing?

I've already deleted and created the type personas again, I've also tried creating the type inside the procedure, but it can't insert into the table

Comment: Get rid of VARRAY. Try using Nested table or Associative array.

Comment: I wish I could, I have to use varray, it's an exercise

Comment: use [personas_array.extend()](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_adv_plsql_extend_method.htm) to make it larger before assigning a value to that index.

Comment: Using the extend method it says "subscript outside of limit"

Comment: Update: it was the extend method because thanks to that I've managed to fill the table changing i for a value, now I need to find why it doesn't accept i as index

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few tips for a SQL beginner:

Don't learn 30 years old Oracle join syntax. Use modern ANSI join syntax, i.e.

```
SELECT * 
FROM empleados 
   JOIN departamentos ON empleados.dept_no = departamentos.dept_no;
```

Your cursors are redundant. Either use

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR cur_departamento IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM departamentos;   
BEGIN
    FOR departamento IN cur_departamento LOOP
       ...
    END LOOP;
END;
```

or

```
DECLARE 
BEGIN
    FOR departamento IN (SELECT * FROM departamentos) LOOP
       ...
    END LOOP;
END;
```

You can also use this:

```
DECLARE 
    CURSOR cur_empleados(d IN EMPLEADOS.DEPT_NO%TYPE) IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM EMPLEADOS
    WHERE dept_no = d;

   /*
   -- Do not use this!
    CURSOR cur_empleados(dept_no IN EMPLEADOS.DEPT_NO%TYPE) IS
    SELECT * 
    FROM EMPLEADOS
    WHERE EMPLEADOS.dept_no = dept_no;  -> will return all rows
    */    

BEGIN
   FOR departamento IN (SELECT * FROM departamentos) LOOP
      FOR empleado  IN cur_empleados(departamento.dept_no) LOOP
         ...
      END LOOP;
   END LOOP;
END;
```

According to my feelings, VARRAYs are often part of student material but hardly used in real life.

Using string `'NULL'` is most likely not want you want. Use literal `NULL`, i.e.

```
DIRECCION(departamento.loc, NULL, empleado.dir)
```

Type `VARRAY(5) OF PERSONA` defines a varray with **maximum** size of 5 elements. When you initialize it with `personas_array := personas();` then the actual size is 0. You need to extend the varray.

You code may look like this:

```
DECLARE 

    nombre_grupo VARCHAR2(15); 
    direccion_tipo direccion;
    persona_tipo persona;
    personas_array personas;

    i INTEGER;
    
BEGIN
    FOR departamento IN (SELECT * FROM departamentos) LOOP
        nombre_grupo := departamento.dnombre;
        i := 1;
        personas_array := personas();
        FOR empleado IN (SELECT * FROM empleados WHERE dept_no = departamento.dept_no AND ROWNUM <= 5) LOOP
            direccion_tipo := DIRECCION(departamento.loc, NULL, empleado.dir);
            personas_array.extend();
            personas_array(i) := PERSONA(empleado.emp_no, empleado.apellido, direccion_tipo, empleado.fecha_alt);
            i := i + 1;
        END LOOP;
        INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (nombre_grupo, personas_array);
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Just a note, such procedure would have rather low performance. The professional way of doing it would be a Nested Table and then insert the data with a single command:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE personas_NT AS TABLE OF PERSONA;

INSERT INTO grupos VALUES (nombre_grupo, personas_array)
SELECT dnombre, 
    CAST(MULTISET(
        SELECT 
            emp_no, 
            apellido, 
            DIRECCION(dept.loc, NULL, dir), 
            fecha_alt
        FROM EMPLEADOS
        WHERE dept_no = dept.dept_no
    ) AS personas_NT) AS personas_array
FROM DEPARTAMENTOS dept;
```

But maybe, that would be a chapter in the "advanced" SQL course.

Comment: This is sooo complete it'll come in handy in a future haha. I solved it thanks to the extend method, but there also was an error in the insert values script. Anyway, solved! Many thanks